# Why does jax.grad(lambda v: jnp.linalg.norm(v-v))(jnp.ones(2)) produce nans?

Tags: python, jax, automatic-differentiation

Can someone explain the following behaviour? Is it a bug?

```py
from jax import grad
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.ones(2)
grad(lambda v: jnp.linalg.norm(v-v))(x) # returns DeviceArray([nan, nan], dtype=float32)

grad(lambda v: jnp.linalg.norm(0))(x) # returns DeviceArray([0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

I've tried looking up the error online but didn't find anything relevant.

I also skimmed through https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compute `grad(lambda v: jnp.linalg.norm(v-v))(x)`, your function looks roughly like this:

```
f(x) = sqrt[(x - x)^2]
```

so, evaluating with the chain rule, the derivative is

```
df/dx = (x - x) / sqrt[(x - x)^2]
```

which, when you plug-in any finite `x` evaluates to

```
0 / sqrt(0)
```

which is undefined, and represented by `NaN` in floating point arithmetic.

When you compute `grad(lambda v: jnp.linalg.norm(0))(x)`, your function looks roughly like this:

```
g(x) = sqrt[0.0^2]
```

and because it has no dependence on `x` the derivative is simply

```
dg/dx = 0.0
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ooh that makes a lot of sense! I did the algebra to see if there was anything fishy, but for some reason I had put the squared norm instead of the norm. That's crystal clear, thank you!